# Data Structure: Logical error in a linear search program

Tags: search, data-structures

The following function is supposed to execute a linear search.

```
int linsearch(T arr[],int size,T target)
{
    int begin;
    int loc;
    bool found;
    for(begin=0;begin<size&&target!=arr[begin];begin++);
    loc = begin;
    if(target==arr[loc])
        found = loc;
    else
        found = -1;
    return found;
}
```

However, not matter what I search, I always get `1` as the output. This happens when the element is in or out of the array. Please help.

Comment: there should not be ; after for loop statement. instead of bool variable use an int variable to store index

Comment: Please do _not_ change the very nature of the question. It's okay to augment with extra information but changing its essence totally breaks the Q&A concept. You need to ask a _different_ question since it is indeed a different question. Reverting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool found;
:
return found;
```

Boolean values are generally limited to true/false, which is often repesented as 1/0. There's a good chance that placing a non-zero value into a `bool` will coerce it to `1`.

If you want to return the index where it was found, you should probably use an `int`:

```
int found;
```

However, even if you make that change it won't work:

```
int linsearch(T arr[],int size,T target)
{
    int begin;
    int loc;
    int found;  // <<-- changed this
    for(begin=0;begin<size&&target!=arr[begin];begin++);
    loc = begin;
    if(target==arr[loc])
        found = loc;
    else
        found = -1;
    return found;
}
```

That's because, in the event you don't find the item, `begin` (and `loc` since you set it to `begin`) is left as `size` so you're checking beyond the ends of the array with `arr[loc]`.

You really should check for that condition *properly* immediately after the loop, with something like (removing `loc` altogether since it's unnecessary):

```
if (begin == size)
    found = -1;
else
    found = begin;
```

In any case, your code could probably be *substantially* less verbose:

```
int linsearch (T arr[], int size, T target)
{
    int loc;
    for (loc = 0; loc < size; loc++)
        if (target == arr[loc])
            return loc;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @kusur, it doesn't work because you use bool. Even if you use an int, it won't work as is. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I understand your view about out-of-bound index. However, one thing that I am unable to understand is that if the array goes out of bound, then the condition `if(target==arr[loc])` must be false and hence the code must go to the `else` part but it is not.Is it just a fluke on the system's side ( as it is comparing `target` with some garbage value and that value happens to be equal to `target` ) or is there some logical explanation for this?

Comment: @kusur, your contention that it must be false is wrong. It may be that the next memory location after the array holds the `target` variable itself in which case it will _always_ be equal (effectively `if(target==target)`). Bottom line is that the behaviour is most likely undefined hence anything can happen.

Comment: So, it is a fluke that the `target` is equal to `arr[10]`.